# Change Strange Date Format into Actual Date Format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a spreadsheet with this non-conventional date format:

Dates in spreadsheet
[image]

I have followed the advice I found here, and elsewhere, to try to convert these weird dates into dates recognized by Excel, without any joy.

Is it possible to take these strange dates and make them into real dates?

Thanks!

Craig

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", " ", 1), "-", ", ")
```

Format the result in your preferred date format.

Alternately, simply use Text to Columns, Fixed Width, Next, Date: MDY, Finish on the original data.

Comment: Nice use of the last parameter in *Substitute()*